# Set variables for PHP files, so I could include these variables everywhere

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, svg, include

I have SVG icons in PHP files, for example `google-plus.php`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path class="button-icon" d="M23,11H21V9H19V11H17V13H19V15H21V13H23M8,11V13.4H12C11.8,14.4 10.8,16.4 8,16.4C5.6,16.4 3.7,14.4 3.7,12C3.7,9.6 5.6,7.6 8,7.6C9.4,7.6 10.3,8.2 10.8,8.7L12.7,6.9C11.5,5.7 9.9,5 8,5C4.1,5 1,8.1 1,12C1,15.9 4.1,19 8,19C12,19 14.7,16.2 14.7,12.2C14.7,11.7 14.7,11.4 14.6,11H8Z" />
</svg>
```

I need to create variable `$icon_google_plus` associated with this file to include it and display the SVG code easily everywhere in my template (I'm using WordPress).
If you can, I would like examples, how to include that variable in these situations (**TheVariableHere** = included `$icon_google_plus`):

### Situation 1 - PHP

```
function download_link($atts, $download_title) {
    $download_link = $atts[link];
    $download_description = $atts[description];
    return '<div class="download">  TheVariableHere  <div class="download-info"><a href="'.$download_link.
    '">'.$download_title.
    '</a><br><span>'.$download_description.
    '</span></div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('download', 'download_link');
```

### Situation 2 - HTML

```
<li>
<a href="/обратная-связь" class="icon" title="Обратная связь">

TheVariableHere

<span>Обратная связь</span>
</a>
</li>
```

**I'll be very grateful!**

*Sorry, I'm very dumb in PHP, it's very hard to learn it even with tutorials.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing `svg` in `PHP` file put the code in PHP global variable and declare this in `function.php` so you can use it anywhere in theme.

```
global $googlePlusIcon;
$googlePlusIcon = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="button-icon" d="M23,11H21V9H19V11H17V13H19V15H21V13H23M8,11V13.4H12C11.8,14.4 10.8,16.4 8,16.4C5.6,16.4 3.7,14.4 3.7,12C3.7,9.6 5.6,7.6 8,7.6C9.4,7.6 10.3,8.2 10.8,8.7L12.7,6.9C11.5,5.7 9.9,5 8,5C4.1,5 1,8.1 1,12C1,15.9 4.1,19 8,19C12,19 14.7,16.2 14.7,12.2C14.7,11.7 14.7,11.4 14.6,11H8Z" /></svg>';
```

Comment: Can't get it to work here: `function download_link($atts, $download_title) { $download_link = $atts[link]; $download_description = $atts[description]; return '<div class="download"><div class="download-info">'.$googlePlusIcon.'<a href="'.$download_link.'">'.$download_title.'</a><br><span>'.$download_description.'</span></div></div>';}add_shortcode('download', 'download_link');`

Comment: First declare `global $googlePlusIcon;` in your function `download_link`